# Prolog query in code

Tags: prolog

How do you execute a query in the code?

For example:

```
person(abe,instructor).  
person(bob,student).  
person(cindy,student).  
person(david,student).  
person(abe,student).  

% Like this, but this does not work  
% :- person(X,Y).
```

After loading the program, I can run the following query: person(X,Y).

How can I run this query as part of the program itself so once the program loads, it will run the query and output:

```
X = abe,  
Y = instructor ;  
X = bob,  
Y = student ;  
X = cindy,  
Y = student ;  
X = david,  
Y = student ;  
X = abe,  
Y = student.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just create a new predicate.. 2 different ways here. The first finds all person(X,Y), puts them into a list AllPeople, then writes it out.

The second is a 'failure driven loop' which does the first match, writes it out, then tells prolog to try again ie' fail', which continues until there are no more matches, and then matches the second predicate of the same name, to ensure that the predicate finally returns true.

```
showpeople1 :-
    findall(X/Y, person(X,Y), AllPeople),
    write(AllPeople).

showpeople2 :-
    person(X, Y),
    write(X), write(','), write(Y), nl,
    fail.

showpeople2 :- true.



?- showpeople1.
[abe/instructor,bob/student,cindy/student,david/student,abe/student]
true.

?- showpeople2.
abe,instructor
bob,student
cindy,student
david,student
abe,student
true.
```